# How to hide a form field in hook_node_view()

Tags: 7, nodes

```
function hook_node_view($node, $view_mode, $langcode) {
// How can I hide a field in the hook_node_view() using $node
// In my case the field is an image file field
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. [`hook_node_view()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_view/7) exists only to

> Act on a node that is being assembled before rendering.

It can't be used to alter the node's edit form.

You need to use [`hook_form_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) or [`hook_form_FORM_ID_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_FORM_ID_alter/7), to alter form elements e.g.

```
function MYMODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'article_node_form' && $some_other_condition) {
    $form['some_element']['#access'] = FALSE;
  }
}
```

Comment: so by the above code the field will be hidden .?

Comment: Setting `#access` to `FALSE` will stop the element from being rendered at all, yes

Comment: `$node->content['field_element']['#access'] = FALSE;` worked for me in hook_node_view() .Cant we use this in hook_node_view? are there any drawbacks for using above code in hook_view_node?